# Delete Actions - Kony Visualizer

Tags: temenos-quantum

new to kony visaulizer, I have created some actions, i cannot see a way to detele them from the visualizer, Does anyone know if this can be done.

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With latest Visualizer 7.x, you can easily delete the mapped actions in easy ways.

1. Select the widget for which actions to be removed. Go to actions tab. Click on the blue link button. Unnamed actions will be unmapped and deleted automatically.
   [Deleting action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OP5l.png)
2. Alternatively named actions can be removed deleting the actions at Project->Actions tab.
   [Deleting action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBOMV.png)
3. Alternativey any action can be deleted by unmapping the action as mentioned in method 1 and deleting the same in physical folder structure: ProjectDir/studioactions//action_name.js(and .json)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about this.

1. Go to the "Properties" pane on the right, to the "Action" tab, press the "Edit" button on the event to which you've attached the action and delete it from there.
2. Go to the "Project" tab under the left pane and drill down the project tree to the "Actions" node. Click under "Mobile", "Tablet", or "Desktop" to list all the actions defined for each channel, right click, and delete it from there.